# Search Element for Case Insensitive String

Tags: jquery, string, lowercase

Let's pretend I have these spans:

```
<span>c2alerts</span>
<span>C2alerts</span>
<span>c2Alerts</span>
<span>c2aLerts</span>
<span>c2alErts</span>
<span>c2aleRts</span>
<span>c2alerTs</span>
<span>c2alertS</span>
```

And I wanted to find every 'c2alerts'
I am familiar for searching for a specific string:

```
$("span:contains('c2alerts')").addClass('yellow');
```

But how would I search for ALL of them without duplicating coding?
I know I could use the toLowerCase() function, but I'm unsure where I would apply it...

I want to maintain the original formatting of the spans, so converting them to lowercase and THEN searching won't be a feasible option.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use `.filter()`:

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('c2alerts') !== -1;
}).addClass('yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can roll out your own `contains` with custom behaviour

```
jQuery.expr[":"].contains_ignoreCase = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
     return jQuery(elem).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  };
});


$("span:contains_ignoreCase('c2alerts')").addClass('yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is this:

```
$("span").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == "c2alerts") {
        $(this).addClass("yellow");
    }
});
```